# Can beta mods suggest questions to be advertised cross-network?

Tags: feature-request, advertising, beta-phase, site-promotion

At present, StackExchange sidebars feature ads for questions at other SE sites. At present, these questions are chosen automatically - I believe it's high-voted questions with high-voted answers, like the newsletters.

However, sometimes there are other questions which may not be as active, but which might be a good choice to promote across the network. What's popular for a wide audience might be different than what's popular among a group of devoted enthusiasts; similarly, some questions may be opportunities for a beta site to branch out and stretch beyond its present scope.

For example, this idea occurred to me since Writers.SE got a pair of [excellent](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/5139/best-practices-for-maintaining-documented-code-examples) [questions](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/5136/how-do-you-build-good-per-book-and-global-indexes) in the tech-writing field, which is on-topic for us but hasn't gotten a lot of activity. I think these questions would be *great* to promote, because a lot of people *outside* our current user base might be interested in them. However, I have no way to mark these questions for any kind of promotion.

Hence I suggest there be some way that a beta community be able to mark certain questions for promotion, beyond the automatic selection.

Comment: Related: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/937/170

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm not sure whether there will be a way for mods to formally suggest questions for the house ads (as you stated in your question, they're chosen algorithmically, and new features are determined by our dev team), but I created a [Google Form you can use](https://docs.google.com/a/stackoverflow.com/spreadsheet/viewform?formkey=dEM0RjNXT3hpZUNpRFZaU2ZqSGpQb0E6MQ) if you'd like to submit questions to be shared on the Stack Exchange [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/stackexchange) and [Google Plus](https://plus.google.com/101120115153580954446/posts) pages.

Those pages are Stack Exchange's official brand pages and are 100% run by human beings, and we are happy to have help finding the best content from our network to share with the general public. It's obviously a different platform than utilizing our house ads on the network, but I think they work towards the same goal.

(You can fill out that Google form multiple times if you have multiple posts that you think represent your site well.)

A temporary solution, but it's something, so I hope it helps. :)

<sub>**Note:** This is not meant to discourage you from sharing questions to your own social media profiles; you can and should continue to do that - earn badges from it! We already share questions via our official brand pages, though, and it's impossible for any one person to stay on top of the awesome content on all 84 sites, so I'm happy to take suggestions from people who know their communities more intimately than I do.</sub>

Comment: Is this^ still up and running? And I have to say, this is extremely hard to find, even if you know what you are looking for.

Comment: @AsheeshR Yes, it's still a thing, but it doesn't get checked often...for the past year, submissions have averaged one post every three months. Soooo....yeah. We don't have a person whose only job is social media, so there isn't a more efficient and better advertised way to collect submissions from mods.